# Como exportar breakpoints en netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, depuración

Se pueden exportar los breakpoints en netbeans?
y si se puede, como se hace?
He leido que en Eclipse si se puede hacer.

Gracias!

Comment: no se me había ocurrido eso, voy a intentarlo a ver si hallo como. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Pues no hallé plugins que lo hicieran ni la opción en las últimas versiones, así que revisé algo de código y la forma de hacerlo programáticamente implica hacer un plugin con las siguientes características:

Tu clase debe de extender `java.beans.PropertyChangeListener`, para que cuando haya un cambio en tu código este influya en el resultado (aunque suene contraintuitivo).

Debes incluir el api del debugger, por ejemplo si estás usando maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.netbeans.api</groupId>
    <artifactId>org-netbeans-api-debugger</artifactId>
    <version>${version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Tu clase puede leer los breakpoints con el siguiente snippet

```
DebuggerEngine _engine = DebuggerManager.getDebuggerManager().getCurrentEngine();
if (null != _engine) {
   ActiveBreakpoints ab = ActiveBreakpoints.get(_engine);
   // aquí exportas al formato que vayas a desear
}
```

No pude llevarlo a la práctica debido a [un error en el repo maven que ya reporté](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-6321), pero con eso deberías de poder guiarte